# check user is logged in to opencart or not - Opencart 3.0.3.2 and Journal 3 theme-

Tags: opencart-3

I need to redirect the customer from the checkout page to the registration page in case the user is not logged in / or when to click on  add to cart  also redirect it to the register page

I tried with the following code(put in /cataloge/controller/checkout/checkout.php)
in the OpenCart Default theme, it works properly.

but with my case Opencart 3.0.3.2 and Journal 3 theme it was not succeded

if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
$this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart', '', 'SSL');

```
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL')); 
}
```

So any idea or solution for this issue

Comment: Check that file not have any modifications

Answer (score 0):

In corresponding controller file use:

```
if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', true));
}
```

Comment: yes, I tested it but it was the same result, no redirect